# How to remove the default product page url in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I have added seo friendly urls in only product pages in opencart. But now my problem is that my product pages open with both urls by seo friendly url and by default opencart product page urls. 
for example: http://oditiwebs.com/herbal/asthamago-dyte
http://oditiwebs.com/herbal/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=88

I want to remove the last one default url. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Those URL's are there should you decide to turn off the SEO URL functionality. They are also not going to affect your SEO rankings, as your store has a `rel="canonical"` which will use the SEO friendly URL, telling the search engines which the correct one is. Removing the ability to use those URL's isn't a 2 minute edit and could have an effect on certain extensions